# /etc/sudoers is world writable and unable to change permissions on macOS M1

Tags: macos, terminal, permission, sudo

I’m developing a web application and I had a problem saving an uploaded photo to a specific file so it can be retrieved from the database. An error occurred that failed to open the file stream. I searched for the problem and one solution was to write in the terminal `sudo chown -some number` and then the directory of the file. I did it but then phpMyAdmin stopped working and whenever I try to open the MySQL database server it won't open and when I try to change permissions it shows

```
sudo: /etc/sudoers is world writable 
sudo: no valid sudoers sources found, quitting
sudo: error initializing audit plugin sudoers_audit
```

I searched for this problem as well and tried a lot of lines and all of them shows the error

`chmod: Unable to change file mode on /etc/sudoers: Operation not permitted`

Comment: So what command did you actually type?  Who is the actual admin of the server?  Can they tell what's been changed?

Comment: Can you screenshot or copy/paste the actual commands and the responses from the Terminal? Re: 'some number' -- It's really important to know what Terminal commands do before typing them in.

Comment: The answer below, or one of the answers to the question linked on top, should fix the `sudo` issue. Please ask a new question if necessary to fix other issues.

Answer (score 2):

`/etc/sudoers` should be owned by `root` and have a group of `wheel` with `0440` permissions. To reinstate this, do:

```
osascript -e 'do shell script "chmod 0440 /etc/sudoers;chown root:wheel /etc/sudoers" with administrator privileges'
```